# MS Graph API large file upload not working from IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

For some weird reason, large file upload with MS Graph API is not working from Edge and IE but working from Chrome just fine and as expected.

```
var auth = 'Bearer 123';
var theFile;
function getSessionUrl(filename){
return `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/<driveid>/items/<itemid>/children/${filename}/createUploadSession`;
}

function chunkedUpload(url,
  file,
  chunkSize = 327680,
  chunkStart = 0,
  chunkEnd = chunkSize,
  chunks = file.size / chunkSize,
  chunksDone = 0,
  fileChunk = file.slice(chunkStart, chunkEnd)) {
  let req = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    fileReader = new FileReader();
  req.open("PUT", url, true);
  req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + chunkStart + "-" + (chunkEnd - 1) + "/" + file.size.toString());
  req.onload = (e) => {
      let response = JSON.parse(req.response);
      if (response.nextExpectedRanges) {
        let range = response.nextExpectedRanges[0].split('-'),
            chunkStart = Number(range[0]),
            nextChunk = chunkStart + chunkSize,
            chunkEnd = nextChunk > file.size ? file.size : nextChunk;
        console.log(((chunksDone++/ chunks) * 100), '%' );
        chunkedUpload(url, file, chunkSize, chunkStart, chunkEnd, chunks, chunksDone);
      } else {
        console.log("upload session complete");
      }
  };
  fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
    req.send(this.result);
  }; 
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileChunk);
}

$("#file").change((event) => {
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  theFile = file;
});

$("#send").click(() => {
    var url = getSessionUrl(theFile.name);
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    headers: {
        authorization: auth
    },
    success: (data) => {
        chunkedUpload(data.uploadUrl, theFile);
    }
    });
});
```

The code is executable but to reproduce the error you have to replace the `auth` with a proper authorization token, `<driveid>` and `<itemid>` with appropriate ids that correspond to your OneDrive.

Comment: One other reason could be the url limit of IE but that does not explain why it would fail in Edge. The url returned by `createSession` can be as long as more than 2000 characters.

Comment: What is the error you see when it fails?

Comment: @Brad According to the code I posted, `createSession` gets through then the options request for the first chunk returns 200 and then silent. No request is sent and IE 11 logs this: `SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied. _display`. http://imgur.com/59CHZDU http://imgur.com/8XttDYO

Comment: Thanks for the info. Based on what you provided it seems like you're hitting a CORS issue. I'll see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide the request and response headers for the OPTIONS request? I want to make sure I'm replicating it exactly.

Comment: @Brad Here is an image of the network explorer: https://i.imgsafe.org/1388676ea8.png

Comment: Thanks for the details - I set up a repro using your code and jsfiddle.net and wasn't able to repro (see http://imgur.com/a/hsSAy ).The CORs request for my repro seems to match what you provided. I tried with edge (Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0, Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14393).

Comment: @Brad Can you post the response you are getting from your session request? Also it seems from your image that you are not using the same url endpoint that I am using. Try using the format like in my code which is `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/<driveid>/items/<itemid>/children/<filename>/createUploadSession`. I am assuming that its because of the url length limit of IE that is 2000 characters. Because you are using `/me/drive/root` it might shorten the url to fit within the limit and that is why its going through. Btw, with Edge I am getting the same error.

Comment: You're right, I did tweak that - let me try it with the actual drive id so we're comparing the same code paths.

Comment: Things worked fine with the equivalent URL to what you used :(

Comment: @Brad How long was your url? Maybe your token is smaller than mine? Try adding an extra dummy url parameter that is really long to reproduce this issue. Also please share the details of your request.